# How can I run two Skype accounts on the same Ubuntu?

Tags: skype

It is possible if I use Windows. Can I do the same thing in Ubuntu ?

In windows all I have to do is :

In the Run window, enter the following command (include the quotes) and press OK:

```
"C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary
```

I know you can use pidgin or empathy but I want to do this feature using the official Skype account.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am using *Ubuntu 17.04* and have Skype beta version 5.4.0.1. and I could not run the second instance via terminal using the `skype --secondary` command.

The new *skype* application is now called `skypeforlinux`, therefore I used this command:

```
$ skypeforlinux --secondary
```

If `skypeforlinux` is not found you can try using the full path:

```
$ /usr/bin/skypeforlinux --secondary
```

If you don't see the `skypeforlinux` application in `/usr/bin/` directory, then it is probably not installed correctly on your machine.

Hope this helps you on newer versions of Skype.

Comment: Only problem now is that it has autologin so even launching a new one logs into the same

Comment: @momo you can logout and login into another account, while remaining active in the primary version. no issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 29):

Run this command on terminal:

```
skype --secondary
```

Comment: That worked like a charm!!! Thanks for sharing!!

Answer (score 13):

`skype --help` gives me this:

```
Usage: skype [options]
Options:
  --dbpath=<path>       Specify an alternative path to store Skype data files.
                        Default: ~/.Skype
  --resources=<path>    Specify a path where Skype can find its resource files.
                        Default: /usr/share/skype
  --disable-api         Disable Skype Public API.
  --callto <nick>
  skype:<nick>?<action>
                        These commands allow Skype links handling.
  --pipelogin           Command line login. "echo username password | skype --pipelogin"
  --version             Display version information and exit.
```

So you can use `skype --dbpath=<path>` to start another instance.

EDIT: Updated my answer according to the comment given by Pavel.

Comment: Thanks !!I used the `--dpath`  method. Didn't know how to use `--pipelogin` :-S

this is the command : `skype --dpath  ~/Desktop/`

Comment: `skype --dbpath ~/Desktop/AnotherSkype`

Comment: @Axel, pipe login simply allows to forward username and password to skype as shown in the help example. It does not however allow to start another instance, so I'd advise you change your answer to "..--dbpath should to id.." instead of "perhaps --dbpath is even better" since it is the only right solution. I mean your answer is marked *Accepted*, so let's make it a bit more accurate. Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 6):

If you use `skypeforlinux` you can have multiple sessions at the same time that keep their login after a restart by using different folders for the `--datapath` parameter

For example:

`skypeforlinux --datapath=/home/user/.config/skypeforlinux.account1`

`skypeforlinux --datapath=/home/user/.config/skypeforlinux.account2`

Comment: In case of snap packaged skype, command will be:
`/snap/bin/skype --secondary --datapath=<your favourite location>`

The location of .desktop file installed from snap package on ubuntu 20.04 will be '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/skype_skypeforlinux.desktop'.

Answer (score 4):

```
skype --secondary &
```

is a slightly more convenient way to start it in terminal. In this case you will be able to close the terminal window easily ::)

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> and type `skype --secondary`